# unionType cannot be generics Function Parameter in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've defined a generics Function, and I'm trying to pass the union of two specific sample of the generics to the function, like

```
function myCommonFunc<T>({
  data,
  render,
}: {
  data: T;
  render: (data: T) => number;
}) {
  return render(data);
}

interface TestX<T> {
  data: T;
  render: (data: T) => number;
}

let z: TestX<number> | TestX<string>;
// let z: TestX<number | string>  is wrong, because T will be number | string


if ((window as any).someUserInput === 1) {
  z = { data: 1, render: (a: number) => 1 };
} else {
  z = { data: '1', render: (a: string) => 1 };
}

// someother function

myCommonFunc(z);
```

and it throw errs.

I guess the reason is the function cannot infer type from the unionType, and If so, what should I do?

I know one solution is to use typeguard of z, like

```
function isTypeA(z: TestX<number> | TestX<string>): z is TestX<number> {
  return typeof z.data === 'number';
}
if (isTypeA(z)) {
  myCommonFunc(z);
}
```

but I think it actually change the structure of the program, and it need lots if-else to just for typescript, which is annoying. Can someone give me some other way to solve it?

==========

update:

François's solution is helpful, but somehow it cannot solve the real situation, actually z is a `state` in React Function Component, and `myCommonFunc` is a Component, and I'll update the real code:

```
interface TestX<T> {
  data: T;
  render: (data: T) => number;
}

function MyCommonFunc<T>({ data, render }: TestX<T>) {
  return <>{render(data)}</>;
}

type myType = TestX<number> | TestX<string>;

const F = () => {
  const [z, setZ] = useState<myType>({ data: 1, render: (a: number) => 1 });
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState<number>(1);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInput === 1) {
      setZ({ data: 1, render: (a: number) => 1 });
    } else {
      setZ({ data: '1', render: (a: string) => 1 });
    }
  }, [userInput]);
  // someOther Code
  return <MyCommonFunc {...z} />;
};
```

So I cannot just move the function call to the `if-else` block. and I'm so sorry that not put the real code at the first time.

Answer (score 3):

This is a hard one. I see 3 solutions:

#### Solution 1

Solution 1 is the one you've mentioned above of using type guards:

```
const isTestNumber = (z: TestX<number> | TestX<string>): z is TestX<number> => {
  return typeof z.data === "number"
}

if (isTestNumber(z)) {
  myCommonFunc(z);
} else {
  myCommonFunc(z);
}
```

It is by far my **least** favorite solution.

#### Solution 2

Solution 2 is to cast `z` before passing it as a parameter. It looks like this:

```
myCommonFunc(z as TestX<any>); // ugly casting
```

I know it's **ugly**, but it's not particularly dangerous since the `z` variable is fully typed above. At least it does not alter the execution of the program.

#### Solution 3

Solution 3 requires some structural change to your program.

What you currently do is you declare the `z` variable, you assign it in an `if-else` statement and then you perform operations on it afterward.

What you could do is wrap all subsequent operations in another generic function.

It looks like this:

```
interface TestX<T> {
  data: T;
  render: (data: T) => number;
}

function myCommonFunc<T>(z: TestX<T>) {
  const { data, render } = z
  return render(data);
}

function allSubsequentOperations<T>(z: TestX<T>) {
  // someother function
  
  myCommonFunc(z);
}

if ((window as any).someUserInput === 1) {
  const z: TestX<number> = { data: 1, render: (a: number) => 1 };
  allSubsequentOperations(z)
} else {
  const z: TestX<string> = { data: "1", render: (a: string) => 1 };
  allSubsequentOperations(z)
}
```

This is what I usually do when dealing with this kind of problem. From the moment `z` is assigned, your whole program becomes generic.

I hope you find these answers helpful,

François

Comment: thanks for your help，and solution 2 is somehow solve my problem! But we both know it's not the perfect solution;

and I've considerd solution 3, but actually the real code is in a react component, and ```z``` is a state, so solution 3 is not properly in this situation, I'll append the real code, and thanks for your solution again!